# Format string on dimenion attributes SSAS

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas

I have a SSAS multidim cube (2012) and I am trying to set format for some dimension attribute (for example percentage - I would like to display 0.12 as 12%).

I have tried with both dot and coma as decimal

I have tried with data types decimal, float and varchar/nvarchar

I have tried setting both the format string and format properties (both together and one at a time)

I have tried other format strings than "Percentage", both the ones that are included in SSAS and custom ones (##.## etc.)

It works for measure but I cant get it to work for any dimension attributes (I got 0.12 instead of 12%).

I know that excel translates all dimension attributes to strings but I don't get this to work in SSMS either.

Do anyone know if this is a bug in SSAS?

I have found a couple of posts like this one: http://www.ssas-info.com/forum/6-ssas-admindevelopers-lounge/2196-format-option-not-working-for-attribute

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround would be to do the formatting via SQL in a named calculation in the DSV, or in a view which the DSV is accessing. Then you would use that column as the name column for your attribute.